# How to solve typeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization

I am trying to use an algorithm from a freely avaliable package to minimize a function. What I am trying to do is attempt to find the minimum without using the gradient. I have the following code:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
# Import PySwarms
import pyswarms as ps
from pyswarms.utils.functions import single_obj as fx
import random
x1 = random.randint(-100,100)
x2 = random.randint(-100,100)

def f(x1,x2):
   formula = (x1 ** 2 + 2 * x2 ** 2 - 0.3 * np.cos(3 * m.pi * x1) - 0.4 * np.cos(4 * m.pi * x2) + 0.7)
   return formula



# Set-up hyperparameters
options = {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w':0.9, 'k': 2, 'p': 2}

# Call instance of PSO
optimizer = ps.single.LocalBestPSO(n_particles=10, dimensions=2, options=options)

# Perform optimization
cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f(x1, x2), iters=1000)
```

However, when I run the code I get

```
2020-04-07 19:52:58,794 - pyswarms.single.local_best - INFO - Optimize for 1000 iters with {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w': 0.9, 'k': 2, 'p': 2}
pyswarms.single.local_best:   0%|          |0/1000Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 26, in <module>
    cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f(x1, x2), iters=1000)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyswarms\single\local_best.py", line 208, in optimize
    self.swarm, objective_func, pool=pool, **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyswarms\backend\operators.py", line 239, in compute_objective_function
    return objective_func(swarm.position, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
pyswarms.single.local_best:   0%|          |0/1000

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone advice me on how to actually get this algorithm to work with the formula I have shown above? so that would be: 
x1 ** 2 + 2 * x2 ** 2 - 0.3 * np.cos(3 * m.pi * x1) - 0.4 * np.cos(4 * m.pi * x2) + 0.7?

I would like to run my code with that formula and find a local optimum, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I could make it work by giving the optimize f.sphere as its first argument, which was just an example, but it does not work with my formula.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The first argument to `optimize()` should be a function. You're passing the result of calling the function.

Comment: @Barmar could you perhaps elaborate? when I simply call it with 'f' I get an error aswell

Comment: I was trying to find details in the PySwarm documentation, but couldn't see where it specified how the function is called.

Comment: @ you can simply change the first argument I have with f.sphere and it should work.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not entirely sure if this is what you were referring to, but I found the [pyswarms.single.local_best.LocalBestPSO.optimize](https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyswarms.single.html#pyswarms.single.local_best.LocalBestPSO.optimize) method. The first parameter: _objective_func (callable) – objective function to be evaluated_, hence the error message which states _'numpy.float64' object is not callable_.

Comment: But it doesn't say what arguments will be passed to `objective_func`.

Comment: @AMC Any ideas on how to solve the numpy.float error? I got that one as well when trying new things.

Comment: @noobmaster69 Yes, pass a callable, not a float.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, _kwargs (dict) – arguments for the objective function_ is all we get unfortunately.

Comment: @AMC could you perhaps explain a 'callable' and how I make sure I input that to the first argument? does this mean I should make a class  that return the function when I call it?

Answer (score 1):

optimize function accepts obj_func as the first parameter

From documentation: https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyswarms.utils.functions.html

For single objective functions present in pyswarm.single.functions

> All objective functions obj_func() must accept a (numpy.ndarray) with
> shape (n_particles, dimensions). Thus, each row represents a particle,
> and each column represents its position on a specific dimension of the
> search-space.
>
> In this context, obj_func() must return an array j of size (n_particles, ) that contains all the computed fitness for each particle.

Try passing numpy.ndarray with shape (n_particles, dimensions) to your custom objective function f.

Hope this solves your problem.